# Hide password field in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I want to hide my password field values like null if values are there in password field but I want to show like null that there is no values but the values is hidden I want to do this thing please help me out.

Comment: what version of SQL Server?

Comment: Usually you do not **store passwords** in a database: you store the **hashes** of the passwords such that it is close to impossible to reconstruct the original password.

Comment: I want to do this thing If some one access my database then my password filed values not showing to him I want to show him null values that there is no password exist

Comment: I am using sql server 2014

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about when you are in Edit mode in SQL Management Studio...

You should probably be storing your passwords hashed and salted if you are not already.  Then you will probably be less concerned about people looking over your shoulder.

Here's a top result from Google:
https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

If you are talking about in a SELECT statement then just don't select that column or select like

```
SELECT [username], NULL as [password] FROM users
```

Comment: My scnerio is that If I want to select table and want to edit top 200 rows then field password must be shown null but on backend the password values are store but viewer see that there is null field

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary that you register the password in an encrypted form in the database and when doing the logical test make the comparison.

This is done directly in the application and not in the bank!

Comment: My scnerio is that If I want to select table and want to edit top 200 rows then field password must be shown null but on backend the password values are store but viewer see that there is null field

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can store in the database hashes, not passwords. But sometimes you need store in the database some sensitive information, which you want to protect from access.

In this case you can use Dynamic Data Masking (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking), but it supported from 2016 version.

For example you can hide entire field:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customers]
ALTER COLUMN LastName ADD MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()');
```

[image]

Or apply partial mask:

```
ALTER TABLE Customers
ALTER COLUMN Phone ADD MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'partial(2, "X-XXX-XX", 2)')
```

[image]